# multiple ng-view wth ng-if

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

In my application the index page is like

```
<div ng-if="isLoggedIn>
   <div ng-view>
     </div>
<div ng-if="!isLoggedIn">
   <div ng-if="type==='admin'">
      <div ng-view>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="type!=='admin'">
      <div>.....</div>
      <div ng-view>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So basically i have different ng-views for different views. The problem here is when user is not logged in ,login page is displayed using ng-view.But upon login the ng-view initializes with login page again (may be becoz of $route.current is already set).

When user clicks log in button he/she is directed to home page and again redirected to login page. so no change is displayed on the page.

This issue can be solved using ng-show/hide insted of ng-if. But that creates another issue that controllers are called twice becoz of two ng-view in the dom and also element can't be referred using id becoz two elements are generated fro the same id. So this solution can't be used.

Is there any way of solving it?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple & Nested `ng-view` won't work on the same page.

You need take a look at [**angular ui-router**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which would be great to use in your case, you could also use nested `ui-view` using angular ui-router
Or may be you can avoid `ng-if` using `ui-router`

Comment: @Anita did you looked at my answer..does it helps you?

Comment: Yes it nice. But in my application changing the structure of routing and view would be difficult. So I changed the code to make only one ng-view and put the condition on other divs to make them display conditionally

Comment: they you could use this by using `ng-switch` with `ng-switch-when`  see this http://plnkr.co/edit/A0e5oKM7lmLrzdPyvMIF?p=preview

Comment: I tried ng-switch but it was not working. It was giving the same result as with ng-if

Comment: then instead of `ng-view` with `ng-if`, try `ng-if` with `ng-include` but it terms of scope hierarchy, it wouldn't be a good idea..